# hyperref links to the wrong page for List of Figures & List of Tables. All other links seem to be fine

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[format=hang,labelsep=period,font={footnotesize},textfont={footnotesize},justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false,pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,pdfnewwindow=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}

\title{Title of Document}
\author{Author's Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
\listoftables
\newpage

\section{Introduction}

This is the introduction.

\subsection{Subsection}

Here is table 1.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c |}
\hline
item1 \\
item2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{This is the caption for the first table.}
\end{center}

Discussion of table 1.

Here is the first figure.

\begin{center}
$$\boxed{i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = i j k = -1}$$
\captionof{figure}{My first figure}
\end{center}
\newpage

\section{Discussion}

Here is table 2.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline
cell1 & cell2 \\
cell3 & cell4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{This is the caption for the second table.}
\end{center}

Now let's discuss this table.

Here is figure 2.

\begin{center}
$$\boxed{e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0}$$
\captionof{figure}{My second figure}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide some short text describing the issue you want to deal with. The title is not explanatory enough. Being precise and thorough guarantees that you will get the best possible answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A very quick fix if neither list is greater than a page is to put the `\addcontentsline` after you call `\listoffigures`/`\listoftables` instead of before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[format=hang,labelsep=period,font={footnotesize},textfont={footnotesize},justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false,pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,pdfnewwindow=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}

\title{Title of Document}
\author{Author's Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures %<--- SWAPPED
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename} %<--- SWAPPED
\newpage

\listoftables %<--- SWAPPED
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename} %<--- SWAPPED
\newpage

\section{Introduction}

This is the introduction.

\subsection{Subsection}

Here is table 1.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c |}
\hline
item1 \\
item2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{This is the caption for the first table.}
\end{center}

Discussion of table 1.

Here is the first figure.

\begin{center}
$$\boxed{i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = i j k = -1}$$
\captionof{figure}{My first figure}
\end{center}
\newpage

\section{Discussion}

Here is table 2.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline
cell1 & cell2 \\
cell3 & cell4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{This is the caption for the second table.}
\end{center}

Now let's discuss this table.

Here is figure 2.

\begin{center}
$$\boxed{e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0}$$
\captionof{figure}{My second figure}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: As @Ulrike Fischer commented a better approach is to use `\phantomsection` which works regardless of the page length of the lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[format=hang,labelsep=period,font={footnotesize},textfont={footnotesize},justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false,pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,pdfnewwindow=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}

\title{Title of Document}
\author{Author's Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\phantomsection%<---
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}  
\listoffigures 

\newpage

\phantomsection%<---
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename} 
\listoftables 
\newpage

\section{Introduction}

This is the introduction.

\subsection{Subsection}

Here is table 1.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c |}
\hline
item1 \\
item2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{This is the caption for the first table.}
\end{center}

Discussion of table 1.

Here is the first figure.

\begin{center}
$$\boxed{i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = i j k = -1}$$
\captionof{figure}{My first figure}
\end{center}
\newpage

\section{Discussion}

Here is table 2.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
\hline
cell1 & cell2 \\
cell3 & cell4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{This is the caption for the second table.}
\end{center}

Now let's discuss this table.

Here is figure 2.

\begin{center}
$$\boxed{e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0}$$
\captionof{figure}{My second figure}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, yes!  Thank you so much!

Comment: That is wrong, if the list has two pages it will show the wrong page number in the toc. Instead add \phantomsection to create an anchor.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right. I just edited my answer to include the `\phantomsection` approach.